# How can I position center1 directly below center3 using css

Tags: css

I am unable to position #center3 directly below #center1.  I have tried floating right and it didn't work, I have also tried using the relative  positioning  but it not also working either.

I have been searching for help on this topic on the Internet for a wile now without any luck. I have also spent some time to see if I can figure it out by my self but it turn out to be too difficult for me.

**HTML**

```
<section>    
   <article></article>    
   <aside></aside>    
   <aside id="center1"></aside>    
   <aside id="center2"></aside>    
   <aside id="center3"></aside>    
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:960px;
}

article {
    width:960px;t turned out to be 
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

aside {
    width:250px;
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:left;
}

#center1 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#center2 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#center3 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: If you post your HTML too, we could possibly make a fiddle to demonstrate/solve the problem

Comment: If you want #center1 and #center2 on one line, and then #center3 on another line, I suggest creating a class called clear, and put `.clear {clear:both;}` then put this after #center2 and before #center3

Comment: @mattytommo HTML is there, its at the bottom of the code :)

Comment: @DanClarke Great spot! If you could please post a pair of glasses as it seems I am partially-sighted. :)

Comment: Are the dimensions of the elements are fixed?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/paZB6/1/
(edit with new fiddle: I added to .right-column a 1px blue border so you can easily visually see what it is doing)

You need to add a `clear` to `#center3` first of all in order to bypass the floats above it.

Further than that however, to keep it from also clearing your aside, you need to wrap the right side elements in a containing element so as to separate those boxes from the aside.

What I have done is to create two columns, your aside, plus whatever remains to the right of it, then your #center1,2,3 boxes are contained inside the box to the right of aside.  Note that you can add width and whatever else to right-column as needed, I have only provided the base functionality.

Note that I also changed your HTML `<section>` that was wrapping everything.  Instead of targeting it in css as section (not best practice for what you are doing), I gave it a class called wrapper and applied your styles to it via the class name.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="wrapper">


<article>
    <p>Some text</p>
</article>

<aside>
</aside>
<section class="right-container">
<aside id="center1">
</aside>

<aside id="center2">
</aside>

<aside id="center3">
</aside>
</section><!-- END RIGHT CONTAINER -->

</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:960px;
}

article {
    width:960px;t turned out to be 
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #333;
}

aside {
    width:250px;
    height:1000px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:left;
}

.right-container {
    float: left;
}

#center1 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#center2 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
}

#center3 {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #333;
    margin-top:5px;
    float:left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hello Michael, Thank you for the answers, it works great!! can I also achieve the same using positioning?.

Comment: I suppose you could but it would not be wise or following best practice.  Layout design 101: Rule #1 - Avoid position: at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `clear:left;` to `#center3`

Comment: This answer should really be as a comment, as it is given as a suggestion rather than a definitive answer.